# Find unique child nodes of an element

Tags: xslt

Need to write an xslt file. Below is the input file:

```
<assets>
    <item>
        <child1>some text</child1>
        <child2>some text</child2>
        <child3>some text</child3>
        <child4>some text</child4>
    </item>
    <item>
        <child1>some text</child1>
        <child2>some text</child2>
        <childx>some text</childx>
    </item>
    <item>
        <child1>some text</child1>
        <childx>some text</childx>
        <childy>some text</childy>
        <childz>some text</childz>
    </item>
</assets>
```

I need to find out all the unique child names of assets/item. The number of children and child name is dynamic under the element (item)
The Output should be as below:

```
<item>
    <columns>
        <columnname>child1</columnname>
        <columnname>child2</columnname>
        <columnname>child3</columnname>
        <columnname>child4</columnname>
        <columnname>childx</columnname>
        <columnname>childy</columnname>
        <columnname>childz</columnname> 
    </columns>
</item>
```

Comment: What have you tried till now ? Please show us some code snippet

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) on the element names - something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="elements" match="*" use="local-name()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="assets/item" />
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="*[count(.|key('elements', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
            <columnname>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </columnname>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will get you this:

```
<item>
   <columnname>child1</columnname>
   <columnname>child2</columnname>
   <columnname>child3</columnname>
   <columnname>child4</columnname>
   <columnname>childx</columnname>
   <columnname>childy</columnname>
   <columnname>childz</columnname>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    <xsl:key name="child" match="item/*" use="name()"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <item>
        <columns>
            <xsl:for-each select="//item/*[count(.|key('child', name())[1]) = 1]">
                <columnname><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></columnname>                    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </columns> 
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

**output**

```
<item>
       <columns>
          <columnname>child1</columnname>
          <columnname>child2</columnname>
          <columnname>child3</columnname>
          <columnname>child4</columnname>
          <columnname>childx</columnname>
          <columnname>childy</columnname>
          <columnname>childz</columnname>
       </columns>
    </item>
```